# 18 Dice Game odds

Tags: probability, dice

My friends and I invented a dice game called 18s to pass the time in between warhammer games.

The premise is simple.

Roll 18 dice. Once rolled, remove all 6s and roll the remaining dice.

Keep doing this until all dice are gone OR you don't roll a 6.

My question is: what are the odds of leaving yourself with 0 dice?

I've been trying to solve it, but it is proving too much.

Comment: Seems like a task for a computer. And, no offense: if a minigame between Warhammer games makes you to ask in a Math forum, what do you do in a real game?? Have you talked to NASA guys?

Comment: The odds are poor.  If you get down to one die, you have $\frac 56$ chance to not roll a $6$.  If you have more dice, the chance of getting all $6$s is small and the chance of no $6$s is rather higher.  I would make a spreadsheet with a line for each number of dice remaining.  Next to it show the probability that you win, which you compute from all the lower numbers of dice times the probability that you roll enough $6$s to get to that lower number.

Comment: Ive manage to complete the game twice. I will take the spreadsheet advice thank you. I appreciate the help.

Comment: The first answer is a little sarcastic.

Comment: Thankfully its not an answer, it is a comment.  That being said, you could also describe this as a 20-state [absorbing markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) and write out the corresponding $20\times 20$ matrix and run calculations on it to find the chance to win (*will require inverting an $18\times 18$ matrix, so not very convenient to do by hand, computer help would be ideal*).

Comment: @JMoravitz An $n$-die game terminates after at most $n$ rolls, so one can compute the appropriate row of $P^n$ Instead of inverting the transition matrix. Still not convenient to do by hand, of course.

Comment: The chance of winning drops very quickly with increasing numbers of dice. With only three dice, it’s already down to around only 4%.

Comment: @amd, my (unreliable?) intuition tells me that the chance of winning tends to a non-zero limit as the number of dice increases.

Comment: @BarryCipran That’s plausible. With larger numbers of dice in play, the likeliest results of each roll will remove more or less a sixth of the dice pool and you’ll eventually get to some of the small cases without perturbing those probabilities much..

Answer (score 0):

Let $p={1\over6}$ be the probability of rolling a $6$ and let $q=1-p={5\over6}$ be the probability of rolling anything else.  If you start with $n$ dice, the probability of winning the game (i.e., rolling *all* $6$'s on a single turn before rolling all *non*-$6$'s) is given by recursive formula:

$$P(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}p^{n-k}q^kP(k)$$

with $P(0)=1$.  If I've done the arithmetic correctly, the first few of these are

$$\begin{align}
P(0)&=1\\
P(1)&=p\\
P(2)&=p^2(1+2q)\\
P(3)&=p^3(1+3q+3q^2+6q^3)\\
P(4)&=p^4(1+4q+6q^2+16q^3+12q^4+12q^5+24q^6)
\end{align}$$

A patient calculator should be able to extend this up to $P(18)$, which will have the form $p^{18}Q_{18}(q)$, where $Q_{18}$ is a polynomial of degree $18\cdot17/2=153$ of the form $1+18q+153q^2+\cdots+18!q^{153}$. I don't recommend doing it by hand!

It's worth noting that if you let $p={1\over2}$ instead of $1\over6$ -- i.e., if you play the game with coins instead of dice, say winning if you toss all heads before all tails (and removing all coins that come up heads on each turn) -- then everything simplifies extremely nicely:

$$p={1\over2}\implies P(n)={1\over2}\quad\text{for all }n\ge1$$

This can be proved by induction from the recursive formula, or, more simply, by noting that no matter which round the game ends on, it ends either in a win where the coins all come up heads, or in a loss where the coins all come up tails, each of which is equally likely.